# Prolog - SWI specifically - where is pl located?

Tags: linux, prolog, swi-prolog, interprolog

I'm trying to set up an environment with interprolog and SWI prolog, interprolog needs the location of swi's "pl" but i cant find it. All i can find is swipl or plrc and neither work with interprolog. If i type pl into the terminal(this should run swi-prolog) it says

```
bash: pl :command not found
```

but if i type in

```
swipl
```

or

prolog

it runs swiprolog fine.

the thing is interprolog requires pl, which i cant seem to find.

anyone have any ideas how i can get around this?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have I understood your question, Is pl a symbolic link to the prolog software? Check the location of the `pl` executable by `where pl` or
maybe you need to make the prolog source code `.pl` executable and add a header at the top of it...

```
#! /bin/swiprolog -f

; Prolog code here...
```

And use `chmod u+x some_file.pl`. Then when bash executes, it checks to see the top bit of the file '#! /bin/swiprolog -f', I'm using the '-f' switch to say pass it into the prolog interpreter...check your documentation...

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Answer (score 1):

```
which swipl
```

will tell you where the swipl binary lives.

However, you need some way to make "pl" mean the same thing as "swipl"

To do that, you need to alias pl to swipl.

The code `alias pl='swipl'` will do that in BASH.

so after aliasing, you could start interprolog from the command line and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you have it worked out. Ideally, this is what you should do:

- Open `runSWISPListener.sh`.
- Change `${SWI_BIN_DIRECTORY}/pl` to `${SWI_BIN_DIRECTORY}/swipl`

It will then work fine.